# Why does postgres date_trunc return the hour 24?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Exactly what the question says.

```
mydb=> select '2016-01-03 24:00'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2016-01-04 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

That's what I expected.

```
mydb=> select date_trunc('seconds', '2016-01-03 23:59.9999999999'::timestamp);
     date_trunc
---------------------
 2016-01-03 00:24:00
(1 row)
```

Um. Wait, what?

Comment: `23:59.9999999999` is 23 minutes and 59.999... seconds.

Comment: in other words, your "um wait" version forgot to specify the hours.

Comment: Yes. But that should wrap over into `2016-01-04 00:00`. There *is* no such time as `24:00`. It behaves the same for `'microseconds'`.

Comment: The result is not `24:00` but `00:24:00`. That is 24 minutes past midnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `date_trunc` ... once you introduce the decimal point, `23:59.9999999999` is being interpreted as minutes and seconds rather than hours and minutes.

**Without decimal point**

```
db=# select '2016-01-03 23:59'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2016-01-03 23:59:00
(1 row)
```

**With decimal point**

```
db=# select '2016-01-03 23:59.9999999'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2016-01-03 00:24:00
(1 row)
```

It's understandable, given what you were expecting to get back, but you seem to have misread 24 minutes as 24 hours in the result here.

As a side note, the rounding kicks in once you go past six digits (i.e. microseconds) after the decimal place:

```
db=# select '2016-01-03 23:59.999999'::timestamp;
         timestamp          
----------------------------
 2016-01-03 00:23:59.999999
(1 row)
```

Comment: I *just* realized that I needed the `23:59:59.99999` :P